# Two submit buttons in Twig

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony, twig

I use **Symfony 2** and **Twig**.

I have a form that contains one submit, this submit calls the function of identifier `tfg_insertarCongreso (form name="formularioRegistro" method="POST" action = "{{path('tfg_insertarCongreso')}}")`.

I need two buttons submit for call two different actions. 
Some idea, please??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve that using just server-side template engine.
Submit buttons cannot change `action` attribute for `<form>`.

You may rather attach javascript handlers that would rewrite `action` attribute for parent `<form>`.

The better way is provide your buttons with different `name` and `value` so on the server side you could differ what the button has been clicked.

Why second way is better? I believe you would have the same validation and authorization check(since it's the same form at the same page) for both cases. So it's easier to handle when it's just single `action` used.